# Azure Function Activity fails in Data Factory when a defined function 'routePrefix' is different than 'api'

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a series of Azure Functions in one of my projects with the following settings in the `host.json` file:

```
{ 
  "version": "2.0", 
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": "v0.1"
    }
  }
}
```

I need DataFactory to trigger one of those Az Functions which url is something like this:

`https://my-function-app.azurewebsites.net/v0.1/FunctionTestDf`.

However, this fails with the following error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "3608",
    "message": "Call to provided Azure function '' failed with status-'NotFound' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - NotFound.'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "AzureFunctionDataReplicationActivity"
}
```

The reason is that DataFactory adds the default `api` prefix to the url, hence trying to call my function api with an url like this

`https://my-function-app.azurewebsites.net/api/v0.1/FunctionTestDf`.

Which returns a `404` response code.

The first issue that I see is that DataFactory is still adding the default `api` prefix even when I'm overriding that in `host.json`

Does anybody know if there is a way in DataFactory to make this work, in other words to force DataFactory to not add the `api` prefix?

**Note:** the only workaround that I have found so far is to set the `routePrefix` as `api/v0.1` and then in the Azure Function activity in DataFactory to set the Function name as `v0.1/FunctionTestDf` but that forces me to include the `api` prefix when I don't necessarily want that